# AEM Component to send data to twitter

Tags: aem

I am new to Adobe Extension Manager. I want to create a webpage with textbox and send button. When I click that button, it should post data in textbox to twitter account.

Can someone help me in achieving this.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is a big task,So go through these steps:

1. integrate twitter with cq using social component.(easily available in AEM documentation)
2. Use twitter api to post your data from aem to twitter.

If you need further help please comment.

Comment: Thanks Shivani!I'm gonna to try this and if I get any issues, will let you know

Comment: coder coder....whatever solution you follow ...pls add as answer.The question is quite interesting...hoping ans will be more..